# Equivalente a 'eventListener' em PHP

Tags: php, event-listener

Eu possuo umá série de classes PHP que montam minhas estruturas HTML com base no Bootstrap CSS ja somadas com suas respectivas ações em Javascript, exemplo essa chamada:

```
$VIDB_button = new \vidbModel\buttonElement();
$btn = $VIDB_button->color('primary')->content('Salvar')->addicionalClassnames('pull-right exec-save-new-company')->event('submit_fake_form')->calls('caller|classname|Classe|metodo')->actions('closeClosestModalOnSuccess|primary-modal|SweetAlertByResponse')->dataType('json')->event_post_content(null)->type('button')->button(0);
```

Esse método faz um botão com as ações de submeter o formulário que ele está dentro, ja indicar os dados concatenados para o POST, indicar o método JS que vai fechar a modal que o formulário está dentro, e responder em um SweetAlert o resultado, indica que e resposta deve ser json, e o método calls indica quais métodos PHP devem ser chamados ao submeter o formulário.

Bom, eu tenho um pequeno problema é que os métodos precisam ser iniciados em um ordem especifica pra isso funcionar, ou seja, se eu alterar qualquer coisa na ordem da chamada alguma coisa não funciona direito.

Eu gostaria de saber como 'ouvir' que um método foi chamado, pra poder tornar obrigatoria a cadencia e retornar um erro caso algo esteja fora do lugar, ex:

'Ouvir que a classe `button` foi chamada' ou 'ouvir que o método `calls` da classe `buttons` foi chamado antes de `event`, e assim informar em um `error` a ordem correta', algo como a função hipotética a seguir:

```
class classe {

    public function observar(){

        if(ClasseAnterior::metodo_observado() == 'foi_chamado'){
            \\verificar a execução do metodo_observado(), poder executar algo antes dele, e depois confirmar a execução do mesmo 
        }

    }

}
```

> Existe algo 'natural' do PHP pra monitorar/ouvir disparos de métodos e
>   classes?
>
> Se não, como poderia ser criado algo relacionado ?
>
> Se não houver como criar algo relacionado, qual seria uma opção viável
>   pra se ter um resultado parecido ?

Comment: Já considerou a utilização do [SplObserver](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.splobserver.php) e o [SplSubject](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.splsubject.php)? Pode implementar uma classe de eventos de uma forma bem [fácil](https://gist.github.com/im4aLL/548c11c56dbc7267a2fe96bda6ed348b) também. Por último, talvez o [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.debug-backtrace.php) te ajude a verificar a ordem das chamadas, mas acredito que um simples observer com uma validação de sequência deva resolver.

Comment: @TomMelo consegue fazer um exemplo minimo de uma observação ?

Comment: Claro, aqui tem um exemplo bem bem básico: https://gist.github.com/tommelo/e9ca08d875e4739a5bff92b8b90bfe2f No seu caso, você precisa implementar as regras de validação de sequência de chamadas em cada instância da classe que você quer observar. Vai dar um pouco mais de trabalho, mas acredito que não seja muito complexo.

Comment: @TomMelo dei uma olhada aqui, realmente é simples, só é massivo pra se fazer, mas vai dar boa, se quiser fazer uma resposta pra eu aceitar, acredito que isso ja solucionou o que eu queria fazer.

Comment: Vou deixar essa pra algum expert em PHP responder, certeza que da pra implementar algo mais fácil e elegante, estou com pouco tempo pra pesquisar mais a fundo. Sucesso nas implementações ae!