# Obrigar sequência de métodos a ter sua chamada em valor default?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho um framework que é usado basicamente na construção de formulários e eventos `HTML/jQuery` com `PHP`, um exemplo de chamada:

```
$VIDB_input = new \vidbModel\inputElement(); 
$documentos_date_action = 'triggered';
$documentos_date_conv = \vidbModel\convertDates::exec_format_date($data[0]['documentos_date'], 'd/m/Y', 'Y-m-d');
$documentos_date = $VIDB_input->value($documentos_date_conv)->field('documentos_date')->mask('date_br_d_m_Y')->name('documentos_date')->type('text')->validator('date_br')->additional_classnames('documentos_date')->datepicker('')->comboAction(true, $documentos_date_action)->comboValue('S/M')->input(0);
```

Essa chamada acima faz a mesma coisa do que isto (existem mais eventos mas não cabem ao exemplo):

```js
        $(document).on('focusin', '.input-field', function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var mask = $this.data('input-mask');
            if (mask === 'undefined') {
                console.log('no-mask');
            } else {
                console.log('put-mask');
            }
        });
    

$(document).on('click', '.combo-action-trigger', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input = $this.closest('.input-group').find('.input-field');
    var previousValue = $input.val();
    var previousMask = $input.data('input-mask');
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        var comboValue = $this.val();
        $input.data('input-mask', 'undefined');
        $input.data('previous-value', previousValue);
        $input.data('previous-mask', previousMask);
        $input.val(comboValue).prop('readonly', true);
    } else {
        var previousValueI = $input.data('previous-value');
        var previousMaskI = $input.data('previous-mask');
        $input.data('input-mask', previousMaskI);
        $input.val(previousValueI).prop('readonly', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="input-group"><input type="text" name="documentos_date" data-input-mask="date_br_d_m_Y" data-input-field="documentos_date" data-input-validator="date_br" value="S/M"class="form-control input-field documentos_date " readonly="true" ><span class="input-group-addon">S/M<input type="checkbox" class="combo-action-trigger" value="S/M" checked="true" ></span></div>
```

O problema acontece na seguinte situação(Para este exemplo, ocorre em todas as situações quando há necessidade de repetir a chamada):

Instanciei um input como no exemplo anterior, e logo em seguida precisar iniciar outro input, mas esse novo input, por exemplo, não receberia nenhum `comboAction` (`comboAction` é o nome dado a ações dentro de um `.input-group`, como no exemplo, alterar o valor de um campo para um valor pré-definido ao marcar o `checkbox`, e retornar ao valor anterior ao desmarcar o mesmo `checkbox`), deste modo ele puxa automaticamente o valor definido na chamada anterior, no caso, ele iniciaria um segundo `input` com o `comboAction` de definir o valor ao marcar o `checkbox` caso eu não defina `false` nessa nova chamada.

O valor `default` para o método `comboAction` é `false`, eu gostaria que, de algum modo, ao iniciar essa segunda chamada, ele não recuperasse o valor salvo na instância, e sim o valor `default` do método, mas isso sem matar a instância, pois posso precisar renderizar dezenas de inputs em um `form` e não é viável reinstanciar toda vez, e isso deve se aplicar a todos os métodos das classes em questão.

- É possível definir (talvez em um construtor? ) que uma classe deva
  chamar X métodos e que se não forem chamados previamente esse
  construtor chame-os como default?
- Se possível, como fazer isso ?
- Se não é possível, há alguma outra solução ? Ou devo reprojetar as classes que dependeriam dessa solução pra funcionar corretamente ?

OBS.: Já fiz um [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250804/equivalente-a-eventlistener-em-php) parecida, mas o problema era com a ordem da chamada, esse problema já foi resolvido com o comentário deixado, restou apenas esse problema com resíduo de valor na instância.